# How to remove extra data from XML attributes

Tags: xml, powershell

I apologize if the title is a little vague. I'm not sure what the terminology is for what I'm looking for. I'm currently importing information from XML into a powershell script. I've tried it two ways, one doesn't return any data, and the other comes back with extra characters. It needs to work in Windows 7 with PS v2.

If I try to put information into the variable this way the variable is empty:

```
$applist = $UninstallXML.Uninstall.HP.App.Search
```

If I try this way I get the correct list, but it comes with extra characters

```
$applist = $UninstallXML.Uninstall.HP.App | Select Search
```

Comes back with...

```
@(Search=*Bing*)
@(Search=*Evernote*)
@(Search=*Energy*Star*)
etc...
```

How do I remove everything else so it's just the list of search values?

UPDATE:

If it helps anything, here's more a complete picture of what I'm doing.

```
[xml]$UninstallXML = Get-Content "$dir\Files\Uninstall.xml"

$applist = $UninstallXML.Uninstall.HP.App | Select Search

ForEach ($prog in $applist) {

    $app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | where { $_.Name -like "$prog" }

    If ($app.IdentifyingNumber -ne $null) {

        $index = [array]::IndexOf($applist,$prog)

        $name = $UninstallXML.Uninstall.HP.App[$index] | Select Name

        $logbox.Items.Add(" Uninstalled $($name)")
        start-process -filepath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/x $($app.IdentifyingNumber) /passive /norestart" -wait
        "   Uninstalled $($name)" >> $logfile

    } # End If

} # End ForEach
```

The Get-WmiObject line doesn't find anything because it either has the extra info and there are no matching program names, or there's no list to check.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I got it to work with this...

$applist = $UninstallXML.Uninstall.HP.App | Select -expandproperty Search

Answer (score 0):

```
$applist = ($UninstallXML.Uninstall.HP.App | Select Search).search
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however that seems to bring me back to no output at all.